# Can installing two python versions can cause problems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-3.9

I've install 3.7.9 and 3.9.7 and installed some packages (including pandas and numpy) but after doing so running or using them in programs some of them are executable in first or second versions of the python how to overcome this ?
Should I just delete any one of the version or there is any remedy for this

Comment: you can create a virtual environment using a specific python version that you want to use.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple python versions without a problem. Whenever you install a package though, it will only be installed into one of the two python versions. You therefore need to install once for python 3.7.9, and once for python 3.9.7. Depending on which OS you are running, you can run the different versions through `python3.9` or `python3.7`. Lets say you want to install pandas on python3.9, you run `python3.9 -m pip install pandas`.

In general, it is a good idea to use virtual environments (see [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for example). This will install all the dependencies that you have for a project separately. In the long run, such approach will avoid problems with compatibility after upgrading to newer python versions or package versions.